# Topological sort to find dependencies of a specific node

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science, topological-sort

Given the following [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Directed_acyclic_graph.png):

[image]

What algorithm can I use to output topological ordered lists with tasks to complete, and that are relevant for just for a specific node?

For example, considering the `node 2`, the list should be:

```
7, 5, 11, 2
```

or

```
5, 7, 11, 2
```

Comment: So, you don't care about the order of the nodes? In that case, you don't actually want topological sort.

Comment: I not understand. Required output all nodes or only part?

Comment: @svick don't care about the other nodes

Comment: @Толя don't care about the other nodes

Comment: @svick: he does care about the order of the nodes, but the order of `7,5` vs `5,7` is free. Those two must come before `11` and `11` must come before `2`. The question calls for a topological sort of the subset of the input nodes from which `2` is reachable. For this example there are precisely two admissible outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Reverse the edges
2. Run a DFS starting from `2`
3. Upon leaving a node, insert it into the list.

Example:

```
Enter 2
  Enter 11
    Enter 7
    Leave 7, insert into list
    Enter 5
    Leave 5, insert into list
  Leave 11, insert into list
Done, insert 2 into list

Result: 7, 5, 11, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to decompose the graph into an adjacency matrix, in which every link from Node A to Node B is represented as a "1" in a matrix in which nodes correspond to nodes and columns.

From this point, all you need to do is work backwards from a terminal node, identify the nodes that are pointing to it, and then work backwards from each of those as well.

Now, you would probably want to do this in a breadth-first way, so use a queue data structure to keep track of "dependent" nodes.

Comment: I don't think that the first sentence of this answer is correct - topological sorting (and variants thereof) does not require the creation of an adjacency matrix.  That may be one approach, but it is not a necessary step.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Even though that's what the question says, topological sorting is not actually what the question is asking for.

Comment: Answering this question doesn't necessitate the construction of an adjacency matrix, though it might be a useful step.